# Angular 2: summing 2 numbers with ngModel

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to sum ngModel variable with another variable and display the result as interpolation but I don't see the result updated dynamically.

Here's my input text field:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]='downpayment1' class="form-control" placeholder="Option 1 Down Payment (%)">
```

typescript code looks like this:

```
  downpayment1 = 0;
  result = this.downpayment1 + 20;
```

changing downpayment1 input should also change {{result}} but it doesn't happen. It was much easier to evaluate a numeric expression with Angular1 but I can't find any example of this with Angular2. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your code is unclear in the extreme. Please post a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: I'm trying to update the result variable when I change the input value that is bound to a ngModel variable. result value should be 20 + whatever the input value is provided.

Comment: That's a link to a "Hello World" example. It doesn't use a numerical value or anything else (besides an input) from your question.

Comment: I know. Sorry about that. I modified that example to my code but don't know how to save my work- embarrassing

Comment: this is my code: https://plnkr.co/edit/4gPYktI5gWlhMchpKRuH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand correctly what you are trying to achieve is:

- **display** ngModel value **summed** with some fixed value
- **keep ngModel value untouched** by this fixed value...

then that would be my answer

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <h1>Summing example</h1>
    <h2>Fixed value {{fixedValue}}</h2>
    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]='downpayment1' class="form-control" placeholder="Option 1 Down Payment (%)">

    <h2>Sum : {{ fixedValue + downpayment1 }}</h2>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    public fixedValue: number = 20;
    public downpayment1: number = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Tried your code and it works.